# Output of this C program

Tags: c

What should be the output of this C program?

```
int main()
{
    int x=1,y=1,z;
    if (z=(y>0)) x=5;
    printf("%d %d",x,z);
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, the output is X is 5 and Z is 1. This is because when expression y>0 is evaluated it is true and so on and so forth. Now the problem is in this program:

```
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    for (y=1;(x=y)<10;y++)
    ;

    printf("%d %d",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

should not the output be an infinite loop? Reason being, (x=y) will always return true(1), which is always less than 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `(x=y)` returns the new value after setting x to y's value.

However, `(x==y)` returns 1 if they are equal, and 0 if not.

Answer (score 2):

`x = y` is an assignment, you're confusing it for `x == y`. What actually happens is that `x` takes `y`'s value and then it's compared to 10 until the `< 10` condition stop being true.

And in your example, `y == 1` (initially) and `x` is no initialized so `x == y` would not necessarily be true.

Comment: There is no such thing as not having a value I'm C. When entering the loop test for the first time `x` is uninitialized. The value of `x` can be anything including 10.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because at some point y evaluatess to 10 is assigned to x. The value of the assignment is 10 therefore not less than 10. The loop terminates.